# Losing binded value after successfully receiving it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, binding

The issue I have is the following.
I have an angularjs project and I'm trying to communicate two components using one way binding. I'm passing some objects from one component to another. I can see, that the objects I'm passing are received on the second component and everything seems to be working fine. But then I need to use this passed objects inside of a promise. Something like this

```
loadSomeStuffById(stuffId) {
   this.service.loadStuffFromServiceById(stuffId).then((responseData) => {
      this.filteredDataList = this.filterResponseData(responseData);
     if(this.objectReceivedFromBinding.HasSomeProperty()) {
         //do something with it
     }
  });
}
```

And if I use debugger to look at the binded data state I get the following: Before entering the service function, binded data is there, but inside the promise it becomes *undefined*.
*$onChanges()* tracks the change from binded data being a valid object to the undefined state but I can't track down, why this is happening in the first place. It looks like the whole component scope refreshes to the state where it was not having any values passed by binding
One more thing I noticed is that when I look at the code in the browser (so it was put into a bundle)

```
var _this310(or some other number) = this;
```

this line is put before the service function is called

**Edit** So I figured it's not the promise that loses the value of binded variable. It just becomes undefined after time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem with this was not in the same area, in which I was looking for a solution.
Turned out that a component, that was passing the binded values had a ng-click within ng-click, and the second one was reassigning the values. It was fixed with a *event.stopPropagation()* in the inner call of the ng-click